# Split column by delimiter and inserting into different columns

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, csv, select

I have the following data and would like to set a delimiter and insert them into separate columns.

```
select * from name 



John | Kelly | Bick | Henry
Steve | John | Max | Alis | Emily
```

I would like my output to be...

```
name1 name2 name3 name4 name5
John  Kelly Bick  Henry
Steve John  Max   Alis  Emily
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, one option is `split_part()`, if you know in advance the maximum number of values per string. Assuming that your string column is called `col`:

```
select
    split_part(col, ' | ', 1) name1,
    split_part(col, ' | ', 2) name2,
    split_part(col, ' | ', 3) name3,
    split_part(col, ' | ', 4) name4,
    split_part(col, ' | ', 5) name5
from name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split once using `regexp_split_to_array()` and then just extract elements from the array:

```
select ar[1] as name1, ar[2] as name2, ar[3] as name3, ar[4] as name4, ar[5] as name5
from (values ('John | Kelly | Bick | Henry'),
             ('Steve | John | Max | Alis | Emily')
     ) v(names) cross join lateral
     regexp_split_to_array(v.names, ' \| ') ar;
```